Trajectory of a bird flying over the earth
I'm studying the topic of centrifugal force on classical mechanics and I'm having some trouble comprehending the following problem.
Consider a bird flying east at latitude $\theta$ with velocity $v_p$. Consider also the angular earth velocity $\omega$. Now if the bird could fly for unlimited time, it would fly along this curved trajectory around the globe. Considering an observer at the earth surface, it would see a centrifugal force acting on the bird, the weight force acting on the bird and a buoyance force that keeps the bird on the air. The centrifugal force acting on the bird would point otwards the bird trajectory. The weight force would point inwards the center of the globe and the buoyance force would point the opposite direction from the weight force.
My question is, shouldnt the buoyance force and the weight force cancell out? How come there is a resultant centrifugal force that points in a different direction from those?
If I where to evaluate the radius of the bird trajectory, should I consider the velocity of the bird only or the velocity of the bird and the velocity of the earth as part of the centrifugal force?

In addition to bouyancy, there is also an aerodynamic lift force on the bird caused by air moving over its wings. Have you tried calculating the magnitudes of the bouyancy force and the centrifugal force to see if they are at all significant compared to the bird's weight?


it would see a centrifugal force acting on the bird, the weight force
acting on the bird and a buoyance force that keeps the bird on the air

The buoyance force does not keep the bird in the air. If that was true, the bird would be able to hover in still air without flapping its wings. It is the lift force of the bird's wings as it propels itself through the air, that keeps the bird in the air.

If I where to evaluate the radius of the bird trajectory, should I
consider the velocity of the bird only or the velocity of the bird and
the velocity of the earth as part of the centrifugal force?

You should consider the total velocity of the bird plus the tangential velocity of the Earth's surface. Unlike inertial motion in a straight line, rotational motion is not relative but absolute. If you were to stand on some bathroom scales at the equator, your weight would be $m (g-c)$ where g is the acceleration of the Earth's gravity and c is the centrifugal acceleration acting on you due to the rotation of the Earth, so in other words, you experience centrifugal force even when standing still on the surface. These forces do not normally cancel each other so you experie
nce a net downward force that registers on the scales.

My question is, shouldn't the buoyance force and the weight force
cancel out?

Again if you consider standing on some bathroom scales, there is a buoyant force acting on you. If it was true that buoyant force cancelled out gravitational force then you would not weight anything and the scales would register zero weight. Experience tells us that is not true.
Now let's consider a bird flying along the equator. It experiences a lift force ($F_L$) due to its velocity relative to the air. It also experiences a buoyant force due to the amount of air it displaces ( $F_B$) and a downward force due to gravity ($F_G$) and centrifugal force ($F_C$) due to flying in a large circle around the centre of the Earth.
The net force acting on the bird is $$F_N = F_G-F_C - F_B - F_L $$
Assuming the following typical values:
Bird mass $m_b = 0.025 Kg$
Bird density $\rho_b = 70 Kg/m^3$
Bird velocity $v_b = 15 m/s$
Air density $\rho_a = 1.2 Kg/m^3$
Earth radius $R = 6,378,000 m$
Earth surface tangential velocity $v_E = 465 m/s$
Acceleration of gravity $g =9.8 m/s$
$ F_G = mg = 0.025 \times 9.81 = 0.24525 N$
$ F_C = mv^2/R = m (v_E+v_b)/R = 0.025 \times (465 + 15)/ 6378000 \approx 0.00000188 N$
$F_B = \rho_a \times m_b/\rho_b = 1.2 \times 0.025 / 70  \approx 0.00043 N$
$F_L = F_G-F_C - F_B = 0.24481 N$
It can be seen that the buoyancy force and the centrifugal force acting on the bird contribute less than 0.001% of the forces opposing the force of gravity. Therefore 99.999% of the force opposing the force of gravity is due to the lift generated by the bird flapping its wings.

How come there is a resultant centrifugal force that points in a
different direction from those?

Centrifugal force ($F_C$) is always orthogonal to the axis of rotation so this force is always parallel to the equatorial plane while the force of gravity ($mg$) points inwards as depicted in the diagram below;

The Earth is not an exact sphere but an oblate sphere (highly exaggerated in the diagram). When standing at a point that is somewhere between a pole and the equator the force of gravity does not point directly at the centre of the Earth due to the oblateness. The component of the gravitational force that is tangent to the surface of the Earth is equal in magnitude to the component of the centrifugal force tangential to the surface (both components shown red), so a person standing on the surface is not subjected to any net horizontal force. However the components of those same forces that are in the vertical direction (green vectors) do not cancel out, so the person would experience a net downward force. For a bird to remain in the air, it requires an additional force which it gets by propelling itself through the air to produce lift.


The centrifugal force acting on the bird would point otwards the bird trajectory. The weight force would point inwards the center of the globe and the buoyance force would point the opposite direction from the weight force.

Actually, the buoyant force will point in the opposite direction from the sum of the gravitational and centrifugal forces on the air.
You can see that buoyant forces include a part due to inertial forces (in non-inertial frames) by observing a helium balloon in an accelerating car. As the car accelerates forward you will feel pushed backwards into your seat, but a helium filled balloon will feel pushed  forwards.

shouldnt the buoyance force and the weight force cancell out?

No. Birds are more dense than air. Their weight is substantially greater than the buoyant force acting on them.
Maybe consider a blimp or dirigible instead.

How come there is a resultant centrifugal force that points in a different direction from those?

The centrifugal force comes from using a non-inertial reference frame. It has nothing directly to do with any of the real forces. It is simply from the choice of reference frame and can go away by choosing a non-rotating frame.


If I where to evaluate the radius of the bird trajectory, should I consider the velocity of the bird only or the velocity of the bird and the velocity of the earth [...]

It's the latter; the rotation of the Earth must be taken into account.

As pointed out in the answer by contributor Dale, you can make the problem more transparent, while keeping the physics the same, by making it about an airship.
When in flight an airship is neutrally buoyant, and an airship has propulsion, so it can maintain a specific velocity relative to the Earth.
An airship has machinery to adjust its buoyancy (otherwise the airship would not be able to descend or ascend.) I will refer to that as 'trimming for neutral buoyancy'.
For simplicity I will discuss the case of an airship in flight over the equator. That is, at all times the velocity is in the plane of the Equator. For other latitudes the forces involved have to be split into components.

I will use uppercase $\Omega$ for the angular velocity of the Earth, and lowercase $\omega$ for the angular velocity of the airship. More specifically, for the angular velocity of the airship with respect to the Earth (angular velocity relative to the Earth), I will use $\omega_r$
For an object that is stationary with respect to the Earth (at the Equator) the required centripetal acceleration to remain co-rotating with the Earth is about 0.0339 $m/s^2$. That amount of acceleration is much smaller than the gravitational acceleration at the Equator. Providing that amount of 0.0339 $m/s^2$ goes at the expense of the amount of gravitational acceleration.
At different latitudes the measured gravitational acceleration is different. At the poles the gravitational acceleration as measured by a gravimeter is the strongest, and at the Equator the gravitational acceleration as measured by a gravimeter is the least strong.
That difference is partly due to the fact that the polar radius is smaller than the equatorial radius. (The difference is about 21 kilometer, on a total Earth radius of about 6400 kilometer.)
But about 70% of the difference is due the fact that for an object that is co-rotating with the Earth a centripetal acceleration is required to make it co-rotate with the Earth. Providing that centripetal acceleration goes at the expense of the amount of gravitational acceleration (as measured by a gravimeter.)
(The true gravitational acceleration can be inferred: for the Equator: just add that value of 0.0339 $m/s^2$ to the value as measured by a gravimeter. But since gravitational mass and inertial mass are the same there is no way to measure the true gravitational acceleration directly.)

So: how will the airship be affected when it goes from zero velocity wrt the Earth to having a velocity wrt the Earth?
Notation:
$R$ radius of the Earth
$\Omega$ angular velocity of the Earth
$\omega_r$ relative angular velocity of the airship
$v_a = \omega_r R$ velocity of the airship
When the airship has a velocity relative to the Earth the total required centripetal acceleration is $(\Omega + \omega_r)^2R$
What we need here is the difference with the stationary-with-respect-to-the-Earth situation, so we subtract the centripetal acceleration for the stationary airship case:
$(\Omega + \omega_r)^2R \ - \ \Omega^2R$
$\Omega^2R + 2\Omega \omega_r R + \omega_r^2R - \Omega^2R$
$2\Omega \omega_r R \ + \ \omega_r^2R$
Use $\omega_r R=v_a$ to change to an expression in terms of $v_a$:
$2 \Omega v_a \ + \ \frac{v_a^2}{R}$
In the above the second term is far, far smaller than the first; the second term has division by the Earth's radius. For the purpose of this question it is sufficient to consider only the first term:
$2 \Omega v_r$
When the airship is flying along the Equator in west-to-east direction with a velocity $v_r$ relative to the Earth then the airship is circumnavigating the Earth's axis at a slightly larger angular velocity than the Earth itself. Therefore a slightly larger centripetal acceleration is required, the magnitude of the additional required centripetal acceleration given by the expression $2 \Omega v_r$
When the airship makes a U-turn, and commences to move in east-to-west direction the airship is circumnavigating the Earth's axis at a slightly lower angular velocity than the Earth itself. Now a little bit less centripetal acceleration is required, the magnitude of the difference given by the expression $2 \Omega v_r$.
That is to say: after a U-turn the airship has to retrim its buoyancy back to neutral buoyancy.
(By contrast: on a non-rotating planet the buoyancy of the airship is the same in both directions.)


This physical effect has a name; it is named after the scientist who first recognized it, and explained it: Eötvös effect

So it is definitely not sufficient to consider only the velocity of the airship relative to the Earth. You have to take into account that the Earth as a whole is rotating.
